# iOS - Timer selector thread

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, timer, selector

I have a Swift code,

```
var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

This code is run from main thread, let say, `viewDidLoad()`. I wonder if this selector, `updateAction()` is guaranteed to run in the main thread or not. In other words if I have UI operations inside `updateAction()` should I explicitly wrap the code on main thread or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Timer` will always run on your main thread, so you can always update your UI in your `updateAction()`.

Comment: I was wondering if there is any guideline from apple regarding this concept. Does selector always run in main thread no matter from which tread it is being called? Any kind of reference? Thanks.

Comment: Yes it will always be called from the main thread for the `Timer`. Apples [reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer) for Timer.

Comment: What if you start the Timer from a different thread? Can we say that the block runs in the same thread where the Timer is scheduled?